# How can I restrict access to a folder or a file to other users in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, restrict

I want to restrict access to some folders and files but only when a user tries to access to it through the url, not when the website access to these files. For example restrict the folders images, javascript,...
I tried in different ways but I always got error 500.
Basically, I don't want external users to list my website directory and open their files, if it is possible to accomplish.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ..

Comment: Which version of apache are you using? What have you tried? Did you research the same?

Answer (score 1):

This is pure mod_rewrite based solution:

```
RewriteRule ^(includes/|submit\.php) - [F,L,NC]
```

This will show forbidden error to use if URI contains certain paths.

Comment: I just have to copy and paste this in the htaccess?

Comment: Read this:
https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a 500 error because the  container cannot be used in an htaccess file (which is essentially all inside a directory container for the directory that it's in). What you need to do is remove the  container from your htaccess file, and leave the Deny from all bit:

htaccess file in your document root:

```
Refuse direct access to all files
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Then create an htaccess file in the `uploads/files/`, `uploads/images/pages/` and uploads/images/store/ (and whatever other directories that you want to allow access to):

```
Allow from all
```

Comment: Inserting this code in my htaccess y get the 500 internal server errorRefuse direct access to all files
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1

Comment: Can you explain a bit more the result of it?

Answer (score 0):

put .htaccess and edit with "Deny from all".
That's it.